# How to create signup button like this in android studio?

Tags: button

how to create button like this.I am new in android.I am trying to create this from last 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can create XML using designer in Android Studio or
Go to `res/layout/activity_main` then XML file will be open then add

```xml
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Button"/>
```